# Signing manifest files with Mage on CloudHSM

Tags: mage, amazon-cloudhsm

Trying to sign application manifest files with mage on AWS CloudHSM.
I have verified all the prerequisites are installed and all configurations are in place.
I can sign .ps1 .exe and .msi files with no problem using signtool.
When I try to sign using the same certificate with mage, I get this error:

```
This certificate cannot be used for signing - "<THUMBPRINT>"
```

The certificate is the same one I use in signtool...

Tried using the -csp argument and passed "Cavium Key Storage Provider" but it did not help.
I saw this post: [mage.exe manifest signing with certificate stored in AWS CloudHSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752638/mage-exe-manifest-signing-with-certificate-stored-in-aws-cloudhsm)

Hacking mage.exe is not an option.
Went through the various GitHub issues, looks like this is the last word about it:
https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/256
Still open

Is there a way to achieve this?